# How to make AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am aware this question has been answered before but I am somehow unable to hit an action within my controller.

Here is the Action

```
public JsonResult GetUpdate()
{
    //get a list of valid elements
    var result = getContent();
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In my script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetUpdate")',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (constraints) {
        alert("Application updated");
    },
    error: function (ex) {
        alert('Failed to retrieve update.' + ex);
    }
});
```

Using fiddler I can hit GetUpdate but from the browser the Ajax call fails. Am I correctly accessing the URL?

Update:
The following is the error message:
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - protocol://localhost:port/Controller/@Url.Action(%22GetUpdate%22)"

The following works through Fiddle:
protocol://localhost:port/Controller/GetUpdate

Comment: Try setting the URL to `GetUpdate`.  Also, pay careful attention to the relative path.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? how do I do that? I thought @url.Action generated the relative path?!

Comment: I think so you are missing the controller class name in which `GetUpdate` is defined

Comment: According to the error message (see update) this is not the case. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor code (C# and all other server-side script) is only executed from `.cshtml` files, therefore C# and Razor can't be used in `.js` files.
 `'@Url.Action("GetUpdate")'` doesn't generate a URL, it's just a string, therefore you are trying to request `protocol://domain:port/Controller@Url.Action("GetUpdate")` which doesn't **exist**.

Here's what you can do:

- In the `.cshtml` file you can store the generated URL in a JavaScript variable and pass it to the external JS file.
- You can move your external JavaScript to the `.cshtml` file so you can use Razor.
- use a  relative string path like `/Controller/GetUpdate`

I would recommend the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out,where _ApplicationPath is protocol://localhost:port/

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: _ApplicationPath + "/ControllerName/GetUpdate",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (constraints) {
        alert("Application updated");
    },
    error: function (ex) {
        alert('Failed to retrieve update.' + ex);
    }
});
```